# Draw NxMx3 ndarray as image using matplotlib imshow

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

My code aims to draw a HSL W x H image in the form of RGB using matplotlib.imshow():

```
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np
import colorsys

W = 512
H = 256

hsls = np.ndarray(shape=(H, W, 3), dtype=float)
hsls[:] = .0

baseCol = np.linspace(0, 1, H)[np.newaxis, :].transpose()
print baseCol.shape, hsls.shape # Gives: (256, 1) (256, 512, 3)
hsls[:, :, 0] = np.tile(baseCol, (1, W))
hsls[:, :, 1:3] = 0.5 # Use constant saturation and lightness.

vfunc = np.vectorize(colorsys.hsv_to_rgb)
rgbs = np.array(vfunc(hsls[:, :, 0], hsls[:, :, 1], hsls[:, :, 2])).transpose()

im = plt.imshow(rgbs, interpolation='nearest', aspect='auto')
plt.colorbar(im, orientation='horizontal')
plt.show()
```

The result:
[image: transposed image]

This looks almost right, except that it's transposed. I'd like it to look rotated counter-clockwise. But when I transpose/reshape it this way:

```
rgbs = rgbs.reshape((H, W, 3))
```

I got a horizontally cascaded image:
[image: Horizontally cascaded image]

I also played around with reshape()'s order argument, but 'F' gives me the first result, while 'C' gives me the second.

How to achieve what I want, i.e., the counter-clockwise rotation?

Comment: Are you looking for [`np.rot90`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rot90.html#numpy.rot90)?

Comment: @cel , thanks! I think that'll work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NumPy arrays of shape `(W, H)` have `W` rows and `H` columns. If you want `H` rows and `W` columns, then the array should have shape `(H, W)`.

So use

```
hsls = np.zeros((H, W, 3), dtype=float)
```

I think everything else follows naturally (without flipping or transposing) if
you start from an array `hsls` with the right shape:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import colorsys

W = 512
H = 256

hsls = np.zeros((H, W, 3), dtype=float)

baseCol = np.linspace(0, 1, H)
print baseCol.shape, hsls.shape
# (256,) (256, 512, 3)
hsls[:, :, 0] = baseCol[:, np.newaxis]
hsls[:, :, 1:3] = 0.5 # Use constant saturation and lightness.

vfunc = np.vectorize(colorsys.hsv_to_rgb)
rgbs = np.dstack(vfunc(hsls[:, :, 0], hsls[:, :, 1], hsls[:, :, 2]))

im = plt.imshow(rgbs, interpolation='nearest', aspect='auto')
plt.colorbar(im, orientation='horizontal')
plt.show()
```

yields

[image]

Note that this result is a vertical mirror image of the result you posted. But
since this image comes without flips or transposes, I think perhaps it might
actually be the result you want. (The image you see has the same orientation as
the numbers you would see if you were to print `hsls`. The upper left corner
corresponds to `hsls[0,0]`, whereas in your image `hsls[0,0]` corresponds to the
lower left corner despite what the tick marks say. You can test this assertion by putting `hsls[:10,:10,:] = 0` before the definition of `rgbs`. You'll see a little black square in the corner where `hsls[0,0]` is located.)

---

To generate the vertical mirror image, call `ax.invert_yaxis()`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import colorsys

W = 512
H = 256

hsls = np.zeros((H, W, 3), dtype=float)

baseCol = np.linspace(0, 1, H)
hsls[:, :, 0] = baseCol[:, np.newaxis]
hsls[:, :, 1:3] = 0.5 

vfunc = np.vectorize(colorsys.hsv_to_rgb)
rgbs = np.dstack(vfunc(hsls[:, :, 0], hsls[:, :, 1], hsls[:, :, 2]))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(rgbs, interpolation='nearest', aspect='auto')
plt.colorbar(im, orientation='horizontal')
ax.invert_yaxis()
plt.show()
```

yields

[image]

Notice that this also inverts the tick labels, showing that 0 starts in the lower left corner.

Comment: Thanks. This is very informative. I do want the image to look like the one in my own answer, but your description really helps me understand the whole thing better.

Comment: In that case, you could also use `ax.invert_yaxis()`. I've edited the post to show what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out myself. I can create the right shape in the first place.

```
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np
import colorsys

W = 512
H = 256

hsls = np.ndarray(shape=(W, H, 3), dtype=float)
hsls[:] = .0

baseCol = np.linspace(0, 1, H)[np.newaxis, :]
print baseCol.shape, hsls.shape # Gives: (256, 1) (256, 512, 3)
hsls[:, :, 0] = np.tile(baseCol, (W, 1))
hsls[:, :, 1:3] = 0.5 # Use constant saturation and lightness.

vfunc = np.vectorize(colorsys.hsv_to_rgb)
rgbs = np.flipud(np.array(vfunc(hsls[:, :, 0], hsls[:, :, 1], hsls[:, :, 2])).transpose())

im = plt.imshow(rgbs, interpolation='nearest', aspect='auto')
plt.colorbar(im, orientation='horizontal')
plt.show()
```

The result:
[image]

Comment: From your original `rgbs` array you could also have swapped the order of the first two dimensions, e.g. `np.transpose(rgbs, [1, 0, 2])` or `np.rollaxis(rgbs, 1, 0)`

Comment: @cel, Yeah, just fixed it.